# Sandcastle Help File Builder and Tools - error : Unresolved assembly reference: mscorlib with UWP Prism Project

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, prism, sandcastle, prism-6

1. In VS 2017 I have installed [Toolkit Template Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AliHK-MSFT.ToolkitTemplatePack)
2. Create Project with Template with "Prism Toolkit Hamburger Menu App "
3. Add Missing Nuget Packages ( Prism.Windows & Prism.Unity)
4. Compile and Run the Project. - It work fine
5. Create Sandcastle Help File Builder and Tools 2017.5.15.0 Project
6. Add the Project Output or .csproj file in documentation source.
7. Set Project Framework to .NET for Universal Windows
8. Choose HTML Help 1 File as help file format.
9. Compile the project .
10. ERROR "MRefBuilder : error : Unresolved assembly reference: mscorlib (mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e, Retargetable=Yes) required by Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation [C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\App1andDependantDocumentation\Help\Working\GenerateRefInfo.proj]

    ### " Project even did not compile.

Normal UWP App project work but UWP and Prism project not working
additional link 
[Unresolved assembly reference: System](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/67) 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestion from the [Unresolved assembly reference: System](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB/issues/67)

1. Open Project Properties
2. Plugin > Assembly binding Redirection > Add
3. Select Tab Ignore If Unresolved
4. Add Assembly name as "msscrolib" > Add > Click OK
5. Now Compile the Project . It will compile and will create the documentation
   [image]